# Ubuntu 20.04 infinite loop on reboot, with three services of systemctl

Tags: 20.04, live-usb, crash, reboot, live-cd

Ubuntu Mate 20.04 crashed and enters an infinite loop on reboot, trying and failing to start the following systemctl services:

1. Stystem Logging Service (rsyslog.service),
2. D-Bus Message System Bus (dbus.service), and (3)
3. Login Service.

(There is no other OS on the machine.)

My two question are (my machine has a CD drive):

1. Isn't there a CD somewhere that will take control of the computer, and fix whatever is wrong? Or,
2. isn't there a CD somewhere that will take control of the computer, erase absolutely everything, and install a new operating system?

Either of those is all I want.

The screen printout is as follows:

> ```
> [   OK   ] stopped **System Logging Service**
>
> starting **System Logging Service**
>
> [FAILED] Failed to start **Login Service**
>
> see 'systemctl status rsyslog.service' for details
>
> [   OK   ] Stopped **Login Service**
>
> [   OK   ] Listening on **D-Bus System Message Bus Socket** 
>
> Starting **Login Service**
>
> [   OK   ] Started D-Bus **System Message Bus**       *These two lines are repeated five times*
>
> dbus.service                                          *These two lines are repeated five times*
>
> [FAILED] Failed to start **D-Bus System Message Bus**
>
> see 'systemctl status dbus.service' for details
>
> [FAILED] Failed to start **System Logging Service**
>
> see 'systemctl status rsyslog.service' for details
>
> [   OK   ] Stopped **System Logging Service**
> ```

... and so on, over and over.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your install media can be used to boot into a live environment. You can than chroot into the installed enviroment and attempt a manual repair.
2. The install media can be used to re-install.

Ubuntu generally requires a DVD though to fit the installer. I'd recommend Knoppix if you have to try to rescue from a CD.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix the existing installation, then reinstall the system using a wired internet connection, either using a live disk, or in the recovery mode:
`sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
The wired connection will ensure proper installation and updates.